# How to paint over the number of cells which I specify in other cell?

Tags: macos, microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

If in A1 I write 5, this action must fills cells A3,A4,A5,A6,A7 with red colour. Is it possible in Excel 2016 on Mac? How to specify point from what excel must count the number from A1? What if I wanna write 3 in A1 and this action must fills cells from C5 to C9?

Comment: You can use conditional formatting to color a cell. Each cell needs to have a different criteria.

Comment: @LPChip, what exactly criteria I need to set up? I seeing some forums but those posts and answers related to windows users, there are other interface and i don't have some options on Mac. And I still don't understand how to set up conditional formatting for my task.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Excel 2016, but in Excel 2011 Mac, you

1. Highlight the range you want to format and choose New Rule from the
   Conditional Formatting dropdown on the Home tab.  Or choose
   "Conditional Formatting..." from the Format menu.
2. Next, you'll have to find the place where you can enter a formula. 
   In Excel 2011, you have to choose the "Classic" style, and then one
   of the choices is "Use a formula..."

[image]

3. Enter the formula in the box as "=(*an expression that does or can
   evaluate to TRUE*)".  The absolute reference to A$1 (in the formula
   shown in the picture) makes it apply to all the cells in the range,
   so you don't have to enter a formula for each cell.
4. Choose one of the available formats, or design your own under
   "custom format...".  You can specify font color, fill and border.

Exit the dialog, and you should get something like this:

[image]

Comment: You would probably want to use the > rather than = so it works with multiple values.